# How to do multiple Exception handling while reading characters from a text file?

Tags: java, exception, bufferedreader

I have referred to earlier threads regarding multiple Exception handling in Java. Yet, when I try to implement in on my code, it fails to compile.

```
try {
    br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(file_name));
    while((r = br.read()) != -1){
        char c = (char) r;
        System.out.print(c);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e ){
    System.out.println("The file was not found.");
    System.exit(0);
} catch (IOException e){
    System.out.println("There was an error reading the file.");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Now I know FileNotFoundException is a special case of IOException and must have multiple catch blocks which is exactly what I am doing, yet, the compiler is not letting me compile it.

Comment: I do not think what you are stating is an issue here... You are not closing while loop properly, one } is missing. Is this just a typo here or it is the case in your code as well. Put } before first catch statement and the code will compile.

Comment: Thanks! This was really silly of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `}` to close your `while` loop. Please correct it.
It should be like this:

```
try {
    br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(file_name));
    while((r = br.read()) != -1){
        char c = (char) r;
        System.out.print(c);
     }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e ){
    System.out.println("The file was not found.");
    System.exit(0);
} catch (IOException e){
    System.out.println("There was an error reading the file.");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: @HarisGhauri glad that it helped

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing brace for your try statement:

```
    try {
            br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(file_name));
            while((r = br.read()) != -1){
                char c = (char) r;
                System.out.print(c);
            }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e ){
            System.out.println("The file was not found.");
            System.exit(0);
    } catch (IOException e){
                System.out.println("There was an error reading the file.");
                System.exit(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your while block is not closed, that's surely a problem.